# spring framework 3.0.5.RELEASE deployments in Codenvy Developer Workspaces vs. Apache Tomcat 7

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, deployment, tomcat7

I am working in the codenvy platform (https://codenvy.com/) developing a spring framework 3.0.5.RELEASE application
having this file web.xml  :

```
<web-app>
   <display-name>Devices Manager</display-name>
   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/sigfox/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and this is my spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

   <bean name="/devices"      class="com.codenvy.example.spring.GreetingController"></bean>


   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
</beans>
```

and this is my index.jsp :

```
 <%
   response.sendRedirect("/sigfox/devices");
%>
```

So when I run the runner everything is fine in the given URL:

http://runnerp11.codenvycorp.com:57342/sigfox/devices

But when I deploy the war in a tomcat 7 (http://139.162.221.XXX:8080/sigfox/devices) I got this error:

```
Estado HTTP 404 - /sigfox/devices
```

http://runnerp11.codenvycorp.com:57342/sigfox/devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe even Tomcat isn't started, have you  tried accessing `http://139.162.221.XXX:8080`

Comment: yes, and I realized that I can access with http://139.162.221.XXX:8080/sigfox/sigfox/devices even all the styles are lost

Comment: Also try this  'response.sendRedirect("devices.jsp");'